# NSMutableArray element access error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray` (named A) of size (2,3). I am able to access the elements when I explicitly specify A[1][2]. However, when I run it through a for loop that says:

```
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for( int k=0; k<2; k++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",A[i][k]);
        }
    }
```

there is `SIGABRT` error during runtime. Of course, the indices are not out of bounds. What is the reason for this error? How can I access the elements using a for loop?

Comment: please show the code where you create / initialize the array and / or where you fill it with values.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using objectAtIndex: instead of the [ and ]?

Comment: @Glorfindel: NO! take a look at objective c literals for arrays.

Comment: NSMutableArray *A = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:A_temp,tempB, nil];


the objects A_temp and tempB are one dimensional arrays

Comment: Do an `NSLog(A)` and add the result to the question. Bet is that it is not fully populated.

Comment: At what indices do you get the error? And show us how `A_temp` and `tembB` are set up.

Comment: I did see my variable. its fully populated!!

Comment: @Rithesh Like, Zaph said, please add the result of NSLog(A) to your question.

Comment: OMG this is amazing! I spotted the problem. Like @zaph pointed out, at this point of the code, A was not fully populated. This is because, A was initialized with another variable A_temp and later in the code, i did a [A_temp removeAllObjects]. This in turn removes the components of A_temp from A. 

HA! its the pointer to the objects that are passed, and not a copy of the object. How do i send the copy now?

Comment: If you want to make a copy use `[array copy]` or `[array mutableCopy]` as appropriate. Note this is why mutable objects are dangerous.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  (You do not specify what the error is, nor do you supply the exception traceback.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to everyone for helping me out!

I got this error, because the elements did not exist. How did they not exist? Read on.

I initialized the mutable array A with two other mutable arrays:

`NSMutableArray *A = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:A_temp,tempB, nil];`

later in the code, before this for loop, I used:

`[A_temp removeAllObjects];`

Since its the pointer to A_temp that is passed to A rather than A_temp's copy, the components were removed from A as well. To counter this error, pass the value as a copy by using the `[array mutablecopy]` method. So the new declaration would be:

`NSMutableArray *A = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[A_temp mutableCopy],[tempB mutableCopy], nil];`